# Angular Renderer2 remove listener

Tags: angular, angular2-render

Is it possible to remove listeners with the new angular 4 renderer?

here is the interface:

```
abstract listen(target: 'window' | 'document' | 'body' | any, eventName: string, callback: (event: any) => boolean | void): () => void;
```

In the renderer v1 listen and listenGlobal returns a Function, but this one returns void.

Is it an issue? If not, how can I remove a listener?

Comment: `but this one returns void.` This one returns function that returns `void`.

Comment: Yes. I think I was sleeping when I read the interface

Comment: I just made the exact same mistake :-) I guess that compact typescript syntax can sometimes be easy to miss when you're working late..

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is no difference with `Renderer`:

```typescript
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent {
  listenerFn = () => {};

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listenerFn = this.renderer.listen(document, 'mousemove', () => console.log('move'));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.listenerFn();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do we really need to do this or would this be handled by Angular?

Comment: @SuyashGupta We need to do this manually. Else it will keep on adding new listeners, along with the existing ones, every time we reinitialize the component.

Comment: can we do like this:
`listenerFn = () => {};`
to avoid the `null check` in `ngOnDestroy();`

Comment: @AqeelAshiq yep

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `fromEventPattern` function from [rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEventPattern).

```js
  private createOnClickObservable(renderer: Renderer2) {
    let removeClickEventListener: () => void;
    const createClickEventListener = (
      handler: (e: Event) => boolean | void
    ) => {
      removeClickEventListener = renderer.listen("document", "click", handler);
    };

    this.onClick$ = fromEventPattern<Event>(createClickEventListener, () =>
      removeClickEventListener()
    ).pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$));
  }
```

just use/subscribe to it as expected

```js
   myMouseService.onClick$.subscribe((e: Event) => {
      console.log("CLICK", e);
    });
```

and dont worry about destroying, it will be handled by rxjs during closing the observable!

live-demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-mouse.service.ts

see another answer, to explore more details: [Is it possible to use HostListener in a Service? Or how to use DOM events in an Angular service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592972/is-it-possible-to-use-hostlistener-in-a-service-or-how-to-use-dom-events-in-an/39593231#39593231)

Answer (score 1):

It’s easier to put the result of the Renderer.listen handler in a variable:

```
listener: any;

this.listener = this.renderer.listen('body', 'mousemove', (event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

and when the cancel event occurs, call the variable with empty parameters

```
this.renderer.listen('body', 'mouseup', (event) => {
  this.listener();
});
```