# Angular using directive for common logic

Tags: angular, dry, angular-directive, angular-components

I have multiple components, that share common logic. I want to move that logic to a single file, so I don't have to copy the code into each component. I though about using a directive.
Would this be the right approach?

The logic is for building a drag and drop style diagram. (Handles the positioning etc...)
So I would need to listen to `(onmousedown)` and `(onmouseup)` events as well and then call the appropriate handlers, which would be located in the directive as well.

So the template of the component would look like this:

```
<div class="entity-wrapper" (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)" (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)">
    <span>{{entityData.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Where `onMouseDown()` and `onMouseUp()` would be the methods found in the directive.

The directive would look something like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDiagramElement]'
})
export class DiagramElementDirective {

  @Input() position: Vector2;

  constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef) { }

  onMouseDown($e: MouseEvent){
    ...
  }

  onMouseUp($e: MouseEvent){
    ...
  }

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove($e: MouseEvent){
    ...
  }
}
```

When I try to do it this way. It doesn't work because the component has no methods `onMouseDown()` and `onMouseUp()`. So I thought, that I might want to create these methods in the component itself and then call the correct implementation in the directive's methods.

How would I go about that or is there a better way?

Edit: Added Template code, where I instantiate the component:

```
<div #wrapper class="diagram-wrapper">
  <app-entity [entityData]="testEntity" class="diagram-element" appDiagramElement [position]="testEntity"></app-entity>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the directive is the right approach.
You'll need to add the event listener dynamically within your directive. For example, in your directive constructor:

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
    // Listen to mousedown events in the component
    renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown', (event) => {
      // Do something with 'event'
    })
);
```

Comment: I'm curious; do you need to remove the listener in `ngOnDestroy()`?

Comment: Thank you very much.
I managed to get it working using this.
I used Renderer2, you might want to update the answer, so its up to date.

Comment: @Silvermind Seems like it can be done this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44454508/12511130
Its the same for Renderer2

Comment: @JanKrüger Thanks for your response. I suspected that one could do it, but I was unsure if you need to. In some cases angular cleans up injected services when a component gets destroyed and it could then automatically 'unlisten'. However, I think the answer could add that information too, to be complete.