# Angular 2+ window.onfocus and windows.onblur

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I need in Angular 2 or 4 to manage when the browser tab of my app is focused or not. Is there any way to use the `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use a component with `@HostListener`.

Something like:

```
@Component({})
export class WindowComponent {

constructor(){}

    @HostListener('window:focus', ['$event'])
    onFocus(event: any): void {
        // Do something
    }

    @HostListener('window:blur', ['$event'])
    onBlur(event: any): void {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Just check that you don't have multiple `WindowComponent` running at the same time, because you will have an unexpected behavior, due that each instance will react to these events.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time my friend. I have a question... How i use this inside a component? I need to use a subscription?

Comment: You are welcome, you don't need to use a subscription, angular will remove the listener when the component get destroyed and the `onFocus` function will be triggered when the browser trigger the `window.onfocus`, same for `blur`.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out this [doesn't work in services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593231), which was my requirement. My solution was doing it "the old way":

```
@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
    constructor(){
        window.addEventListener('focus', event => {
            console.log(event);
        });
        window.addEventListener('blur', event => {
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
}
```

Not sure I did it the "correct" way, but it works on Chrome. What I'm not sure about is if I should destroy the event listener or not, and if it works in other browsers. Let me know if I'm inadvertently shooting myself in the foot here. Will update answer if so, or delete it if need be.

Answer (score 1):

In a more reactive approach, I use this injection token:

```
export const WINDOW_FOCUS = new InjectionToken<Observable<boolean>>(
    'Shared Observable based on `window focus/blurred events`',
    {
        factory: () => {    
            return merge(fromEvent(window, 'focus'), fromEvent(window, 'blur')).pipe(
                startWith(null),
                map(() => window.document.hasFocus()),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                share(),
            );
        },
    },
);
```

Ideally, you do not want to rely on the global windows variable, you could replace it with injecting the WINDOW and DOCUMENT tokens from https://github.com/ng-web-apis/common.

To use the WINDOW_FOCUS injection token, in any component or service, it can be added to the constructor like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(WINDOW_FOCUS) private readonly windowFocus$: Observable<boolean>
    ) {} 
}
```