# Is it possible to have Angular @HostListener('window:scroll',) in simple Service not Component or Directive

Tags: angular, scroll, infinite-scroll

Is it possible to have Angular @HostListener('window:scroll',) in simple Service not Component or Directive code?

I don't want to polute any of my components, since the awareness of scroll should be injected in several other services... Currently i have following code that compiles, but does not work somehow.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Inject, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const scrollStepToReload = 3700;

@Injectable()
export class ScrollWatcherService {

  private maxReachedScroll = 0;
  private lastLoadedAt = 0;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll($event) {

    const scrollOffset = window.pageYOffset || this.document.documentElement.scrollTop || this.document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    console.debug("Scroll Event", scrollOffset);

    if (scrollOffset > this.maxReachedScroll) {
      this.maxReachedScroll = scrollOffset;
    }
    if (this.lastLoadedAt + scrollStepToReload < this.maxReachedScroll) {

      this.lastLoadedAt = this.maxReachedScroll;
      this.searchService.continueSearch();

    }
  }
}
```

Similar code works i Component as desired.
Any ideas how to get it run in a service? or something similar?

Comment: Shouldn't `Renderer2.listen` help you?

Comment: Have you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765844/765965

Comment: @yurzui "Renderer2.listen" has neo meaning to me... Sorry angular beginner

Comment: @Al-Mothafar of course, and it worked on Component, but now trying to listen in a Service

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389002/how-to-listen-for-mousemove-event-on-document-object-in-angular/46389054#46389054

Comment: @yurzui you pointing to "3)" method here? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yep, i was talking about `3`. You can also use method `5`

Comment: Even it's a very valid reference, there is no meaning of wether it can work form service. Examples are with Component. Now i've tried 5)
'  ngOnInit(): void {
     Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll').subscribe(e => console.log('Observed scroll:', e) );

  }' and it doesn't work in service

Comment: @yurzui and same code 5) greatly works if placen in Component... 
With tath i've placed Subscription into one of the components but the logic into the service, so i trigger #onScroll() with scrollOffset manually now... Kinde half of the desired solution with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use HostListener in a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592972/is-it-possible-to-use-hostlistener-in-a-service)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a HostListener in a service. Use the classic:

`window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        console.log('scrolling');
});`