# Angular service doesn't trigger immediate changes

Tags: angular

So because I'm bored and nearly graduated, I'm working on my official portfolio website.
I wanted to challenge myself so decided to program it in Angular, because I have zero experience with it.

I implemented some sort of method that listens to the screenwidth and changes the layout according to the boolean value of the variables inside my header component.

When I noticed I'll also need that functionality on other pages, I stumbled upon services to make that kind of methods global. The issue is that when I toggle between mobile and fullscreen, the changes aren't made by default, so they require a manual refresh, which was not the case when I used the method directly inside my component.

I've searched for fixes and saw things like Observers, ChangeDetectorRef, .., but none of these worked.

Anyone that could have a possible solution?

My header component.html:

```
<!-- Navigation for mobile -->
<header *ngIf="screenwidthService.isMobile">
    <div class="nav-icon-independent">
        <img class="hover" *ngIf="status" src="/assets/img/navOpened.svg" (click)="toggleNavigation()">
        <img class="hover" *ngIf="!status" src="/assets/img/navClosed.svg" (click)="toggleNavigation()">
    </div>

    <div class="nav-sidebar" [class.toggleSidebar]="status">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-ul">
                <li *ngFor="let link of links" class="nav-li hover">{{ link }}</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Navigation for Tablet && Screen -->
<header *ngIf="screenwidthService.isScreen">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-ul">
            <li *ngFor="let link of links" class="nav-li hover">{{ link }}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

My header typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ScreenwidthService } from 'src/app/services/screenwidth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  constructor(
    public screenwidthService: ScreenwidthService,
  ) {}

  // State of the navigation sidebar
  status: Boolean = false;

  // Link tags for navigation
  links = ['Home', 'About me', 'Projects'];

  // Toggles the navigation sidebar in mobile
  toggleNavigation() {
    this.status = !this.status
  }

}
```

The service file:

```
/* 
* Service to listen to the screenwidth 
*/

import { Injectable, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScreenwidthService {

  isMobile: boolean = true;
  isScreen: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.checkScreenSize();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event: any): void {
    this.checkScreenSize();
  }

  private checkScreenSize(): void {
    this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 1079;
    this.isScreen = window.innerWidth >= 1079;
  }

}
```

Comment: Note `status: Boolean = false;` should be `status: boolean = false;` or better yet `status = false` since the type gets inferred. Capital `Boolean` is the constructor type.

Comment: This should technically work I think - Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Preferably in an online code editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: That being said, I think it would be better if your `ScreenwidthService ` defined an observable that is fired with the current values of `isMobile` and `isScreen` and subscribe to it from the different places in your application that need to listen to changes to these booleans.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use HostListener in a Service? Or how to use DOM events in an Angular service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592972/is-it-possible-to-use-hostlistener-in-a-service-or-how-to-use-dom-events-in-an)

Comment: @Cuzy I'll investigate!

Answer (score 2):

HostListeners don't work on services.

You can still define all your logic in your service if you want, but the host listener needs to be in a component.

I might suggest that you add it to your app component (the root component),  Because it will be part of every page (every page gets loaded into its router outlet).  You can then selectively add or remove CSS classes as needed.

You can also use media queries to selectively show or hide the correct header.

You may also want to check out Angular Material's Layout utilities: https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview.  They have a BreakpointObserver class that I think may be what you are looking for.

Comment: The reason I did it conditinally was because of layout purposes

Comment: Of course.  Very common pattern.  I use media queries myself, but the disadvantage to those is that the wrong header will still be loaded into the DOM (as will the correct header), it will just be hidden.

Comment: By the way, If I use it in my root component, do you mean the service of the method I used directly in the header?

Comment: You could do it that way.  So, for example, in app.component.ts you can add the host listener, which will update a property in your service.  Now you can inject that service into anything, and access its properties, just like you are doing in your header.

Comment: Also, if your header is a child of your app.component, you can use an input binding to pass it in: <app-header [isMobile]="isMobile".  This assumes that isMobile is kept track of inside app.component.ts.  That way, you might not need a service (it depends on where, and how many places, you need this functionality.  I'd say if it's more than 2-3 places, or if they are not direct children of app.component, I would use a service.)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!
I'll update you in the future?

Comment: I'm here all week :)

Comment: Small question, in my hostlistener, there was a method (this.checkScreenSize()). How do I import that one correctly?

Comment: Keep your service exactly as is, except remove @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) from onResize.  In app component, add that host listener to a similar method, but that method calls this.screenWidthService.checkScreenSize().  Of course you must remember to inject that service in to app.component.ts (and anywhere else you need it).

Comment: you could use the angular renderer to attach events safely
https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2